# gerund or past simple: "I have registered for 4 classes after meeting (I met) my counselor"

Tags: gerunds, comparison, tense-agreement

I saw that this sentence was not correct:

> I have registered for 4 classes after I **met** with my counselor.

but this one was:

> I have registered for 4 classes after **meeting** with my counselor.

*'met'* and *'meeting'* are both in the past so what is the difference? Both are single events (registered and met). Does **met** reject the action in a **further past** than **gerund**?

Comment: _'Meeting'_ isn't in the past. It is present continuous.

Comment: Who told you that sentence 1 is not correct?

Comment: look at this question Which tense is the right one in this particular example?answered by tromano        not ok  I have registered for four classes after I met with my advisor.

Comment: After I met my counselor, after I had met my counselor, after meeting my counselor, and  having met my couselor are all correct grammatically.

Comment: @Khan. The full sentence in the prior question has aspectual problems. The present-perfect conjunction with the past doesn't fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time reference in a present-perfect construction must not exclude the present.

Can I offer you some breakfast?
--No thanks, I have *already* eaten breakfast. <sup>OK</sup>
--No thanks, I have eaten breakfast *yesterday*. <sup>not OK</sup>

**After I met** excludes the present moment. It is not like date math, where (today is after 1/1/2000) = true.  In natural language (English), "after I met" refers to some time *in the past* subsequent to the time of the meeting.

**After meeting** does not exclude the present.